# Programmatically analyze CSS layout

Tags: php, python, css, statistics

I would like to spider a few blogs and programmatically analyze their html and css-based layouts to see e.g. if the sidebar is to the left or right of the main content, how many columns and how wide they are.

How would I do this the best way? Are there any tools or libraries I can use?

(I would prefer a solution in Python or PHP.)

Comment: It sounds difficult to do this generically. You might be helped by your constraint of only checking blogs, because there might be some uniformity - if for example, they're using a known template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this could be achieved via [PhantomJS](http://www.phantomjs.org/), with a Javascript something like this:

```
phantom.viewportSize = { width: 1024, height: 768 };

var page = new WebPage();

page.open("http://mashable.com/", function(status) {
    if (status === "success")
    {
        page.includeJs("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js", function() {
            var position = page.evaluate(function() {
                return jQuery('#sidebar').position();
            });

            // Now position.left and position.top contains the
            // position of the #sidebar element. Use other
            // jQuery functions to calculate the relative position.

            phantom.exit();
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like an extremely hard task to do using pure server-side CSS and HTML parsing - you would effectively have to recreate the browser's rendering engine to get reliable results.

Depending on what you need this for, I could think of a way somewhere along these lines:

- Fetch pages and style sheets using something like `wget` with `--page-requisites`
- Then either:

  - Walk through each downloaded page using a tool like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/), search for element names and output their positions (if that is possible in Selenium. I assume it is, but I do not know for sure)
  - Create a piece of jQuery that you inject into each of the downloaded pages. The jQuery searches for elements named "sidebar", "toolbar" etc., gets their positions, saves the results to a local AJAX snippet, and continues to the next downloaded page. You need to only open the first page in the browser, the rest will happen automatically. Not trivial to implement but possible.

If you can use a client side application platform like .NET, you may be easier off building a custom application that incorporates a browser control, whose DOM you can access more freely than using only jQuery.

Comment: You could also talk to an instance of Google Chrome over [ChromeDevToolsProtocol](http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/wiki/ChromeDevToolsProtocol).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

http://cthedot.de/cssutils/

It was the first hit on a Google search. There were at least four others that looked promising.  Perhaps you should try Google, list what you found, and ask for specific advice on specific packages.

Comment: looks good now. :) But is this parser really going to be able to calculate the end positions of elements? I'm not sure, as that would require rendering the whole document and predicting the document's flow. Anyway, it might be sufficient for most cases anyway

Comment: What did you search for? I can't find that. Anyway, parsing the CSS is only one step.

Comment: @Christian Davén: "python css parser" http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=python+css+parser&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8.  The other part is downloading sites.  You have `urllib2`, `curl` and http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/python/ for that.  That's equally obvious, I would think.

Comment: I was referring to rendering the page layout, not fetching data via http. Knowing the css for an element doesn't always tell me where it's positioned.

Comment: @Christian Davén: Which browser will you be emulating?  Please update the question to indicate which rendering algorithm you specifically want to see.